# Not able to get response in OUT parameter in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a method where I am executing an Oracle stored procedure and getting the response in `strStatus`. I want that `strStatus` in one parameter in below method.

Here is the code:

```
public void IsSiteIPLValidorNot(string NEID, out string response)
{
    response = ""; 
    string status = string.Empty; 
    bool isIPLNEID = false;

    CommonUser.GET_IPL_STATUS_ON_NEID(NEID); // I want StrStatus response value here
}
```

Method calling with database:

```
public static string GET_IPL_STATUS_ON_NEID(string NEID)
{            
    string strStatus = string.Empty; 
    string strMessage = string.Empty;

    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringAppAuto"].ConnectionString);

    try
    {
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GET_IP_STATUS_PROC"].ToString();

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "P_A6_NEID", Value = NEID, OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "STATUS",
                OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2,
                Size = 500,
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            });

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "MESSAGE",
                OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2,
                Size = 500,
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            });

        if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open) 
            conn.Open();
            
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        strStatus = cmd.Parameters["STATUS"].Value.ToString();
        strMessage = cmd.Parameters["MESSAGE"].Value.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {   
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open) 
            conn.Close();
    }

    return strStatus;            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to assign the result to `response`.

```
public void IsSiteIPLValidorNot(string NEID, out string response)
    {
        response = ""; 
        string status = string.Empty; 
        bool isIPLNEID = false;
        response = CommonUser.GET_IPL_STATUS_ON_NEID(NEID); 
    }
```